# setLngLat().setPopup is not a function

Tags: javascript, ember.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

Once the view render i get this error and popup is not added -

> mapbox-gl.js:176 TypeError: (intermediate value).setLngLat(...).setPopup is not a function(…)

Does anybody face this or know something to fix this?

Code is this to set popup over marker, I've followed this link https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/set-popup/

```
  let tpl;
  if (vendor.get('cachedAverageRating')) {
    tpl = `
    <div class='ui map-marker'>
      <div class="photo">
        <img src="${vendor.getAvatar() || FIXTURE_IMAGE}"></div>
      <div class="ui violet counter">${vendor.get('cachedAverageRating')}</div>
    </div>
  `;
  } else {
    tpl = `
    <div class='ui map-marker'>
      <div class="photo">
        <img src="${vendor.getAvatar() || FIXTURE_IMAGE}">
      </div>
    </div>
  `;
  }

  let markerContainer = document.createElement('div');
  markerContainer.innerHTML = tpl;

  // create the popup
  let markerPopup = new MapboxGL.Popup({offset: 25})
    .setHTML(`<div>Name : ${vendor.get('name')}, Address : ${vendor.get('address')}, Rating : ${vendor.get('cachedAverageRating')}</div>`);

  // create the marker
  new MapboxGL.Marker(markerContainer, {offset:[-25, -25]})
    .setLngLat([get(vendor, 'lon'), get(vendor, 'lat')])
    .setPopup(markerPopup) // sets a popup on this marker
    .addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `MapboxGL` instead of `mapboxgl`, the code is case sensitive.

There may be an error in your vendor variable too, but we can't see how you define it in your answer up there. If you can provide more information we might be able to help further. For now: this bit of code works:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = '<your access token here>';

var monument = [-77.0353, 38.8895];
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
    center: monument,
    zoom: 15
});
let tpl;
​
    tpl = "text";
​
  let markerContainer = document.createElement('div');
  markerContainer.innerHTML = tpl;
​
  // create the popup
  let markerPopup = new mapboxgl.Popup({offset: 25})
    .setHTML("test");
​
  // create the marker
  new mapboxgl.Marker(markerContainer, {offset:[-25, -25]})
    .setLngLat(monument)
    .setPopup(markerPopup) // sets a popup on this marker
    .addTo(map);
```

Comment: MapboxGL is correct. In my case i have initialized 
var MapboxGL = window.mapboxgl;
And then using MapboxGL.

Comment: Would you like to give us more information on your "vendor" variable then?

Answer (score 0):

This should be straightforward for you to debug from the error message. Clearly, `setLngLat()` is returning something which is not a `Marker`, so `setPopup()` is not defined on it.

Why is it doing that? Because you're passing the wrong thing to `setLngLat()`. You should pass a `LngLat` object (defined [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#lnglat)).

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do with your `get()` function, but it's obviously not returning a numbers as required.

Comment: I passing the correct lat lat values. Either we can pass an array in single parameter or in two parameters with (lat, lon)